# Can you define a foreign key in a table from which the table with the primary key is derived?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Let's say I have a table called "Students".

This table has the columns

- StudentId(primary key),
- StudentName,
- StudentSurName.

Let's immagine that from this table I create another table "OriginSurnames" that contains  the country of origin of the distinct surnames of the students in the table "Students".

This table has the columns:

- StudentSurName(primary key)
- Origin

Does it make sense to declare StudentSurName in the table Students a foreign key  condering that I cannot have an entry of "StudentSurName" in the table OriginSurnames if it doesn't exist in the table "Students" .

Comment: Why would you store the length of a surname since it can be retrieved with `CHAR_LENGTH(surname)` ? [DRY !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: Thank you Cid. it was just to give an example. you can substitute it for country_of_origin(country where the surname originates).The important part of the question is the foreign key issue

Comment: To answer your question, if I understand it well, Yes, it makes sense

Comment: For a unique student, there is only one surname, and for a unique surname, there can be many students, right ?

Comment: yes..and  surname cannot exist in the table OriginSurnames if there's no one that posseses it in the table "Students" because the surname is inserted in the table OriginSurnames table after a student with that surname has been inserted in the table Students.

Comment: How is the design method you are following not answering this question? (Rhetorical.--Please give your work following it & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question where stuck. Don't ask us to rewrite it.)

Comment: the solution given by perfomanceDB solve my problem..a long time ago as you can see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

The technical answer is easy, but the problem is a matter of understanding on your part.

Understanding the data (the purpose of modelling), and designing a database (the last step of modelling) is one science, with a complete set of methods and procedures, that have not changed since 1970.  It is an application of Logic, yes, but specifically for data.

Writing code, program design, good practice; etc, is quite a different science.  Although it is a different application of Logic.  If a person is good at one science, they are usually poor at the other.  It is very rare for a person to be good at both ... something which modern coders do anyway, without understanding the relevance of this.  And it always leads to problems.

---

### The Data

> Does it make sense to declare StudentSurName in the table Students a foreign key condering that I cannot have an entry of "StudentSurName" in the table OriginSurnames if it doesn't exist in the table "Students" .

You are getting confused because you are not separating the data (and the Normalisation and design issues that must be considered) vs the program (and what it should do, and when).

Let's take the data, as data, and nothing but data.

- The simple fact is, the `OriginSurname` contains one occurrence of each `Surname`, and `Student` contains many occurrences of `Surname`.  Therefore the relation is one `OriginSurname.Surname` to many `Student.Surnames`.
- Now for the **Consistency** in the database.  You want the `OriginSurname.Surname` to exist only if there is one or more `Student.Surnames`.  That is Cardinality.  The relation is therefore one `OriginSurname.Surname` to one-to-many `Student.Surnames` (as opposed to 0-to-many).

Do not worry about how to obtain that at this point, because that has to do with the program, not the database, and the database is an independent, self-described and integrated storage for the data.

---

### Solution • Initial

It looks like this:

[image: alvyTA1]

#### Note • Notation

- All my data models are rendered in **[IDEF1X](https://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/)**, the Standard for modelling Relational databases since 1993
- My **[IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf)** is essential reading for beginners.

#### Note • Content

You have one good database table `OriginSurname`, and one horrible `Student` file.  Why ?  Because while you have a `Record ID` declared as Primary Key, which ensures the `Record ID` is unique, you have nothing to keep the rows of data unique.   The *Relational Model* demands that the logical rows (as opposed to records) in a table are unique.

This should fail, we want it to fail, but it will succeed:

```
INSERT Student VALUES( "John", "Smith" ) -- should succeed
INSERT Student VALUES( "John", "Smith" ) -- duplicate row: should fail
INSERT Student VALUES( "John", "Smith" ) -- duplicate row: should fail
```

---

### Solution • Corrected

For the columns that you have given, you need an index on `( Surname, Name )`.  Now the rows (regardless of what the `Record ID` is) are unique.  A second `John Smith` will now fail.  It looks like this:

[image: alvyTA2]

Finally ...

> Does it make sense to declare StudentSurName in the table Students a foreign key [referencing the PK in the OriginSurname table]

Yes.  Absolutely.  That is how Referential Integrity is maintained in the database, by the database platform.  Conversely, if you do not declare that Foreign Key, there will not be an integrity between `OriginSurname.Surname` and `Student.Surname`.

---

### The Program

Now we will take up the considerations for the program that is required to maintain the database, and the particular **Consistency** that we have defined in the database.  That is, the Consistency is first defined in the database, and second, maintained by the relevant program components that interact with the database tables.

> surname <strike>cannot</strike> [must not] exist in the table OriginSurnames if there's no one that posseses it in the table "Students"

Agreed.

> because the surname is inserted in the table OriginSurnames table after a student with that surname has been inserted in the table Students.

That is wrong thinking.  In SQL, since 1981, we have had **ACID Transactions**.  We do not write anything to the database via direct `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`, because that would leave the database **In**consistent, especially if the program or the SQL platform, or the computer system, fails.  All writes are properly packaged, and written together, as a Transaction.

1. First understand that the database must be **Consistent**, before; during; and after the writes to the database.  That is the **C** in **ACID**.

   - In our definition, which is correct, `OriginSurname` is the parent row, and we cannot have a child `Student` without a parent.
   - Therefore when a new `Surname` is added to `Student`, it must be `INSERTed` into the parent `OriginSurname` before the `INSERT` into Student.
   - Likewise, when a Student is `DELETEd`, if it is the last occurrence of that `Surname`, the `DELETE Student` must be followed with a `DELETE` OriginSurname.
2. The **A** stands for **Atomic**.  The idea is, a Transaction consists of more than one write to the database, as does ours, and the Transaction is applied completely, or not at all.  Hence Atomic.  The Transaction is bracketed with `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT TRAN` (or `ROLLBACK TRAN` if the code is required to exit a partially applied Transaction).

The `Student_Add` Transaction will be as follows.  I am providing the skeleton code, you need to add error checking, etc:

```
BEGIN TRAN
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1  
        FROM OriginSurname     -- test if parent not exists
        WHERE Surname = @Surname
        )
    INSERT OriginSurname       -- insert parent first
        VALUES( @Surname, @Origin )
INSERT Student                 -- insert child second
    VALUES( @Name, @Surname )
COMMIT TRAN
```

The `Student_Drop` Transaction will be as follows:

```
BEGIN TRAN
DELETE
    FROM  Student              -- delete child first
    WHERE Name = @Name
    AND   Surname = @Surname
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
        FROM Student           -- test if parent obsolete
        WHERE Surname = @Surname
        )
    DELETE
        FROM  OriginSurname    -- delete obsolete parent second
        WHERE Surname = @Surname
COMMIT TRAN
```

The "before" or "after" in your comments simply does not apply, because we are executing an Atomic Transaction, within which we arrange the SQL verbs to match the definition of the database, and we maintain database Consistency throughout.

#### ACID Transaction

To be complete on ACID Transactions:

- The **I** stands for **Isolation**.
  During the Transaction, ie. between the `BEGIN TRAN` and the `COMMIT TRAN`, the changes to the database that are being written, are not complete.  We do not want other active database users to see this incomplete data, precisely because the Transaction is Atomic, they must continue to see only Consistent data.  Therefore the Transaction will be executed *by the platform* in Isolation from the other users.  Nothing for you to do, except to understand that that is how it happens.  It is during this tiny period that resources are locked, and concurrency is an issue (to the extent that it has not been mitigated by OLTP Standards).
- The **D** stands for **Durable**.
  Every Transaction must be durable, ie. once the `COMMIT` has been executed, the Transaction must persist in the database, it must not be lost due to a system crash, or a bomb destroying the building.  That is a facility that the SQL platform provides, in and of itself, nothing for you to do as a coder.  Each platform provides various recovery facilities, and the DBA has to set them up, to the degree that the business requires recovery from a hard crash.

#### Trigger

Do not use triggers.  They cause many more problems than they allege to fix.  More importantly, if you are using Transactions as advised (and no direct writes to the database), there is no need for them.

---

#### Freeware "SQL"

In the first three decades following the advent of the *Relational Model*, and SQL its data sub-language, all SQL platforms were real platforms (Server Architecture; full compliance with the SQL Standard; variety of recovery and Durability facilities; etc).  ACID Transactions have been in the SQL Standard since its first release in 1981.

In the 00's, various pretend-SQL suites became available as freeware; shareware; vapourware; noware; etc.  These are mickey mouse suites (we cannot call them platforms), with no Server Architecture; no decent backup or recovery; and no compliance with the SQL Standard.  Which means their use of the term **SQL** is incorrect.  At best they are pretend-SQLs.

PostgreSQL has no ACID Transactions.  As a sort-of; kinda; looks-like feature, the Functions are declared to be "transactional".  Therefore the Standard SQL `BEGIN/COMMIT/ROLLBACK TRAN` verbs are missing, and you have to place that code in a Function.  And hope there are not too many online users.

MySQL does have transactions, but they are not SQL compliant, ie. they are not true ACID. It should be adequate for the simple kind of work you are doing.  The MySQL verb is `BEGIN WORK`.  And you have to set the table to `TYPE = InnoDB`.

---

Comment: You need to update your information about open source SQL implementations. PostgreSQL supports the standard "START TRANSACTION" statement (feature T241 of the SQL standard), including COMMIT and ROLLBACK for almost two decades now. "BEGIN TRAN" is non-standard syntax used by T-SQL.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt  I am not a PostGres specialist, I get my info from a couple of Postgres specialists who are forever having to change code to make their "trnsactions" work.  First it was "what is a transaction"; then it was "functions are twansactional"; then it was "oh oh use the SQL verbs"; then it was "there is no code behind those verbs" ; ...  It is a mess.  Because it was not SQL.  It is slowly reaching toward SQL.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt  PostGres may have the verbs but it does not provide ACID, as required by the SQL Standard.  Technically, at the principle level, MVCC cannot provide the ACID that is required for SQL ACID Transactions.  (Oracle is not SQL compliant either.)

Answer (score 0):

- For a unique student, there is **only one** surname
- For a unique surname, there can be **many** students

This is a One To Many relation. In such relation, the entity that has the lowest relation (the "***only one***") holds the relation (the Foreign Key)

To answer your question *"Does it make sense to declare StudentSurName in the table Students a foreign key [...] ?"*, not only it does make sense, but this is the **good practice**

This provides :

SurNames :

- SurNameId (primary key)
- StudentSurName (unique index can be used there to make sure there is no duplicate)
- Origin

Prefer using a numeric PK that holds no informations. You may need to edit `StudentSurName` if, in example, you did a typo. A PK is not supposed to be edited.

Students :

- StudentId (primary key)
- StudentName
- SurNameId (Foreign key to SurNames.SurNameId)

---

About SurNames, the design of this table can still be improved.

- For a unique surname, there is **only one** origin
- For a unique origin, there can be **many** surnames

This ends up with :

Origins :

- OriginId (primary key)
- Origin (unique index can be used there to make sure there is no duplicate)

SurNames :

- SurNameId (primary key)
- StudentSurName (unique index can be used there to make sure there is no duplicate)
- OriginId (Foreign key to Origins.OriginId)

Comment: yes but let's say in the table Students i have an entry with StudentName:Bill and SurName:Gates.I would then insert Gates in the OriginSurnames table.If I delete Bill Gates from the Students table, Gates will remain in the table Origin creating a redundancy.OriginSurnames will then no longer be a representation of the origin of surnames of students since it contains an entry that doesn't belong to any student.

Comment: You can delete rows from `OriginSurnames` that aren't used anymore in other tables, using, in example a trigger on `Students` delete

Comment: 1) Your answer does not answer the question directly, you provide sometimes more, and sometimes less that the required info.  Certainly, provide more info in the second half.  Please check & edit. 2) In both halves, you introduce `Record IDs`, which are one **additional** column plus one **additional** index **in each table**.  That (a) provides no value at all, (b) it destroys the Integrity that OP has in his original tables, and (c) forces a JOIN on the intermediate table `Student`.  They can be removed with no loss, the original integrity restored, and the forced JOIN eliminated.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA you would use a column that contains value as primary key ? Values *can* be mutable, and cascading the changes of a PK to the corresponding FK entries can have an impact on performance

Comment: @Cid. 1) I did not write the Law, Dr E F Codd wrote it in the Relational Model in June 1970. The reasons are explained in the paper. I just follow the Law. I have never seen a good reason not to, in 39 years. 2) You cannot add one **additional column and one additional index per table**, which affects every single `INSERT/DELETE`, which is ridiculously poor performance, and then concern yourself with performance when a PK is changes, which affects the tree, only, and once, only. 3) _Mutable_ We are supposed to choose stable Keys, not immutable Keys.  There is no such thing as immutable Key.

Comment: 4) If the data in the universe changes (and it does, _Mary Smith_ marries and becomes _Mary Jones_), then the database that records it has to be changed.  If it is a Key, then the change has to be cascaded.  No problem, because all writes are Transactions, coded in Stored Procs.  Just write another proc, and update in batches of 500 max per Transaction.  5) None of that justifies destroying the Relational Power of Relational Keys: far more database integrity; far fewer `JOINs`; uneventful data transfers; etc.  Especially not, if you count the addition column & Index.